# Format String outputtext primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Im trying to format a String in my view. I have an outputText and i would like to apply a kind of mask like in an inputText.

I mean, I have the value abcdef stored and i would like to show ab-cd-ef.

Thx in advice

Comment: Use a 'converter'...

Comment: Thx i was thinking about something easier like

    <h:outputText value="#{infEconoFinConcepto.anioCero}" >
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00"/>

or convertDate but i guess is not possible

Comment: Uhhhmmm that IS a converter, you might just need a custom one